# Eliminate Intermediate Step in Cast

Tags: java, spring, generics, casting, spring-data

I am using `import org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories` to get an instance of a Spring Data Repository within a Quartz Job.

The `Repositories` class has a `getRepositoryFor(Class<?> domainClass)` method that returns an instance of the respective repository, however the repository is typed as `CrudRepository<Object, Serialiazable>`.

If I attempt to upcast the returned `CrudRepository` to a custom Repository type `CustomerRepository` Eclipse gives informs me I cannot perform the cast.

```
    // Eclipse Error: Cannot cast from CrudRepository<Object,Serializable> 
    // to CustomerRepository
    this.customerRepository =
        (CustomerRepository)super.repositories.getRepositoryFor(Customer.class);
```

However, if I assign the repository to a field of type `CrudRepository<Customer, Long> repository` I can then make a cast to `CustomerRepository`.

```
//No Problems here
CrudRepository<Customer, Long> repository = 
    super.repositories.getRepositoryFor(Customer.class);
CustomerRepository repository = (CustomerRepository) repository;
```

1. Is there anway to avoid this intermediate step necessary to perform
   this cast?
2. What is causing the issue with the first cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the method definition "getRepositoryFor". It doesn't establish a contract for the "T" generic unless you assign it to a variable with the generics defined.

```
public <T,S extends Serializable> CrudRepository<T,S> getRepositoryFor(Class<?> domainClass)
```

I guess the compiler, in that level, can't see that `CustomerRepository` extends `CrudRepository<Customer, Long>`. I think this example will help you understand the issue:

```
public class TestCast {

    public static class MyMap extends HashMap<String, String> {
    }

    public static <T> Map<T,String> getMap1(Class<?> myClass) {
        return new HashMap<T,String>();
    }

    public static <T> Map<T,String> getMap2(Class<T> myClass) {
        return new HashMap<T,String>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Works, because it knows T is String as you state it with the variable type Map<STRING,String>
        Map<String,String> map = getMap(String.class); 

        // Compilation error, it doesn't know T is String and cast won't work either
        MyMap myMap = getMap1(String.class); 

        // Works, because it knows T is String as it is getting it in the method parameter, no need to rely on the variable that is getting the value
        MyMap myMap = (MyMap) getMap2(String.class); 
    }

}
```

This is a complex area in Java and there are some known limitations to reduce the complexity in the compiler.

Comment: So when I do the assignment, what changes or happens that the generic type parameter is known?

Comment: When you do the first assignment, it knows that `T` is `Customer` and `S` is `Long`, because you are assigning an object of the still undefined class `CrudRepository<T,S extends Serializable>` to an variable of the known class `CrudRepository<Customer,Long>`. Then, you can upcast as usual. However, if you skip the first assignment, it cannot see that `T` for `CustomerRepository` is Customer, so it considers `T` as `Object`. Same thing for the S and Long. Then you have the error you pasted: Cannot cast from CrudRepository<Object,Serializable> to CustomerRepository

Comment: Okay, one more question so does it upcast `T` to `Customer` during the assignment?  How does it know the type parameters <Customer,Long> are compatible?  I guess its better said as how does it know the type being assigned is of the type specified by the field?

Comment: What it does is not a cast. With generics, any type you encounter something like `WhateverClass<T>`, a new class is created by the compiler for each possible T in your application. `WhateverClass<String>` is different from `WhateverClass<Long>`. So in your case the compiler needs to know what are the classes for `T` and `S` in order to create the new `CrudRepository` class. The only restriction the method `getRepositoryFor` is imposing is that `S` must implement `Serializable`, as `Long` does.

Comment: If `getRepositoryFor` doesn't actually return CrudRepository<Customer,Long> during runtime, then you will have a Runtime Exception. But the creator of that method assumed that you know the type of your repository you are going to get, so as I said, didn't impose the restriction on the method definition.

Comment: It would just be nice to get the Strong typing without doing the extra assignment.  Even if the method was something like `getRepositoryFor(Repository.class)` instead of using the domain class.  Then using generic methods the method could return the repository type without any casting.

Answer (score 0):

This is about type inference. Say we have method declaration

```
<T> T foo(){ return null; }
```

and a statement like

```
foo();
```

there is not enough information to infer `T` here.

Couldn't compiler use context information to aid inference, like

```
void bar(String str){ }

bar(foo());  // T must be String, right?
```

In general that's not supported; you can imagine how complicate it can get in general.

However in two specific cases, the target type is taken into consideration in type inference

```
String s = foo();   // assign it to a type

String baz()
{
    return foo();   // return it to a type
}
```

---

That is true from Java5 to Java7.

In Java 8, type inference take advantage of more contextual type information, your code may work then:)